# How to organize (and style) my nodejs/expressjs code?

Tags: node.js

I'm rather new to the nodejs environment, trying to learn how to develop real-life projects the 'right' way.

I found Felix style guide very useful: 
https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide

But beyond the styling, when starting to think about the project's organization the picture starts to get muddy very fast.

Any recommendations/guidelines/resources-to-read on how to organize and expose a set of REST API services?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Questions asking for recommendations on off-site resources are considered off-topic here because they tend to attract opinionated answers and sometimes spam.  Instead, try asking about a specific problem you're trying to solve and what you have done so far to solve it.  See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center for more info.   If you're looking for higher-level software architecture and design type advice, you could try asking on http://programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the guidance and the link.